# "wavering into a collusion with..."

Tags: meaning-in-context

In [*Art and Science*](https://books.google.com/books?id=iiE3RsvK248C&pg=PA140&lpg=PA140&dq=%22There%20may%20even%20be%20a%20sense%20that%20on%20our%20behalf%20Hirst%20is%20wavering%22&source=bl&ots=Cu2-icJlw9&sig=PCMQOIUmVvey1ffnRCoXrze14X4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMIspmP54mNyAIVglgUCh1cuAkP#v=onepage&q=%22There%20may%20even%20be%20a%20sense%20that%20on%20our%20behalf%20Hirst%20is%20wavering%22&f=false), Sian Ede discusses an installation called *Last Supper* by Damien Hirst.

Unfortunately, I can not understand the meaning of the following two sentences of the description:

> T*here may even be a sense that on our behalf Hirst is **wavering into a collusion** with the pharmaceutical companies, celebrating the abundant ways of designing pain out of our lives. pharmacologically – and profitably – if you were to read more than cool flippancy into the work.*

Can anybody understand what Ede is saying?

Answer (score 2):

Art criticism (and criticism of most things, really) is not always written in the most direct or accessible language. Depending on what you're reading, sometimes it can be helpful not to read *too* closely into unusual phrasings and just use the phrases that you do understand to gather the meaning.

"Wavering" into a collusion implies passively or unintentionally entering into an agreement or alliance with the pharmaceutical companies, as opposed to actively pursuing such an agreement.

Comment: +1 for the correct answer; if I could, +10 for the warning about art crit.

Comment: Interesting! Can you tell me what is your impression of the whole paragraph? Does it say that Hirst with his installation has praised pharmaceutical companies for inventing new ways of curing our pains, and therefore has unintentionally profited them.

Comment: Basically, yes. My translation: "Hirst has created an installation centered on or inspired by pharmaceutical elements. You can read this as just 'cool flippancy' or parody, or you can see it as Hirst glorifying those elements, even if unintentionally. If the second case, he has then accidentally joined the side of the pharmaceutical companies and helped them celebrate their work."

Comment: @DanBron, so basically art critics communicate in the most roundabout way possible?

Comment: @user1717828 Not the *most* roundabout way possible, no.  Postmodernists are worse :)

Comment: Notice also that the words are never quite right.  The "artist" is using pill bottles in his works.  How is that collusion, which requires some agreement between parties?  "Wavering into a collusion" might mean "inadvertently supporting," but who knows?  Everything is so hedged that it's impossible to tell:  the artist is "wavering," and there "may be a sense," but only if you were to "read into" the work.

Comment: George Orwell in his 1946 essay "Politics and the English Language" warned that "In certain kinds of writing, particularly in art criticism and literary criticism, it is normal to come across long passages which are almost completely lacking in meaning."  Q: What do you get when you cross a Mafia boss with someone like Sian Ede? A:  Someone who makes you an offer you can't understand.